# ARKit - Why is the camera's viewMatrix position changing when the device is rotated?

Tags: ios, 3d, camera, arkit

When I rotate my test device about a certain axis, the camera's viewMatrix's x-axis position value (column 3, row 1) is changing significantly. On the order of a meter in translation along the x-axis when only the device's rotation is changed 180 degrees. If I rotate a full 360 degrees the x position returns to it's starting 0 degree value. I am not translating the device at all (ignoring minor human error).

Is this a bug or configuration setup issue? Can someone explain why the x-axis position would change when only rotating the device? Is anyone else seeing this?

Here is the basic code setup:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ARWorldTrackingConfiguration *arSessionConfiguration;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ARSession *arSession;

- (void)setup
{
  self.arSessionConfiguration = [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration new];
  self.arSessionConfiguration.worldAlignment = ARWorldAlignmentGravity;
  self.arSessionConfiguration.planeDetection = ARPlaneDetectionHorizontal;
  self.arSession = [ARSession new];
  self.arSession.delegate = self;
  [self.arSession runWithConfiguration:self.arSessionConfiguration];
}

- (void)session:(ARSession *)session didUpdateFrame:(ARFrame *)frame
{
  matrix_float4x4 viewMatrix = [frame.camera viewMatrixForOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
  NSLog(@"%0.2f, %0.2f, %0.2f", viewMatrix.columns[3][0], viewMatrix.columns[3][1], viewMatrix.columns[3][2]);
}
```

I am testing on an 10.5" iPad Pro running the latest iOS 11 beta.

Comment: Maybe because the viewport is changing on rotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a mis-understanding: **the 4<sup>th</sup> column of the view matrix is *not* the camera's position.**

This is because the view matrix is the *inverse* of the camera's transformation matrix, i.e. multiplying it by a world point transforms that point to the local basis of the camera.

For a camera with rotation matrix `R` (3x3) and position `c`, multiplying its view matrix `V` (4x4) with a point `p` is equivalent to:

[image]

We can deduce that the view matrix has the following construction:

[image]

> Therefore, to obtain the actual position of the camera, we must
> multiply the 4<sup>th</sup> column by [minus] the transpose / inverse
> of the top-left 3x3 sub-matrix of the view matrix.

I.e., something like:

```
matrix_float3x3 topLeftSubMtx = /*viewMatrix[0][0] to viewMatrix[3][3]*/;
vector_float4 rightColumn = viewMatrix.columns[3];
float positionX = -[vector_float4.dotProduct topLeftSubMtx.columns[0], rightColumn];
// similarly for Y and Z
```

(Apologies as I don't know objective-C or ARKit specifics; hopefully you get the gist of this pseudo-ish code)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my question and provide such a nice detailed response.
I converted your code into objective-c (I'll put it in the next comment, since there is a character limit):
ARKit actually provides a method to obtains the camera's transformation matrix: [camera.transform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2866108-transform). I used your technique and calculated the positionX, Y, and Z values then compared them to the camera.transform matrix's 4th column. The values were identical.

Comment: `matrix_float3x3 topLeftSubMtx = matrix_upper_left_3x3(viewMatrix);`
`vector_float3 rightColumn = viewMatrix.columns[3].xyz;`
`float positionX = -vector_dot(topLeftSubMtx.columns[0], rightColumn);`

Comment: @Awesomeness ahah, nice. Also as a side note, you could just take the dot products of the entire columns themselves, if the last row is `0 0 0 1` (no "skew").

Answer (score 0):

Get current transform of each frame of camera by following method

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) 
{
    let currentTransform = frame.camera.transform    
}
```